# This code is when checkbox 1+2 of more of the checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox

```
    if (q1.isChecked()) {
        int count = 0;
        for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count <= 2) {
            //this Toast will show when only 1 or 2 checkbox will be checked
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.negative), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if(count > 2) {
        }
            //this Toast will show when more than 2 checkboxs will be checked
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.positive), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

what's wrong with the code..whatever i changes the values..it still show negative in 3 checkboxes instead of positive

Comment: your question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving you this answer on basis what I understand from your question...May be your looking for this type of solution...

```
if (q1.isChecked()) {
    int count = 0;
    for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count <= 2) {
        //this dialog will show when only 1 or 2 checkbox will be checked
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(getString(R.string.negative)).show();
    } else {
        //this dialog will show when more than 2 checkboxs will be checked
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(getString(R.string.positive)).show();
    }
}
```

Now my suggestion will be, if you just want to show message in a dialog without any button for further action to take based on that message then you should use `Toast`. Generally, `Toast` will help you to show your message on the screen for short or long time. I'm also giving you the code with `Toast`...

```
if (q1.isChecked()) {
    int count = 0;
    for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count <= 2) {
        //this Toast will show when only 1 or 2 checkbox will be checked
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.negative), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //this Toast will show when more than 2 checkboxs will be checked
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.positive), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hamid..ic got an error here "} else (count > 2) {"

Comment: i add if after the else to solve the problem but is show negative when i check 3 checkboxes @hamid

Comment: check out what value `count` is containing after check 3 `CheckBox`.

Comment: what's wrong with the code..whatever i changes the values..it still show negative in 3 checkboxes instead of positive..i updated my code above..can you fix it for me.? @hamid

Comment: sorry, there was an error in my code...check the update and paste that in your class...it will work Unfortunately, I put a condition after `else` which isn't valid. Now, I removed that condition.

Comment: unfortunately..the result is still d same..when i check 3 checkbox the result is still negative instead of positive.. @hamid

Comment: can you post your updated code...so that I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've correctly implemented a CheckableLayout (for single selection or multiple selection) you could tweak your code like below to achieve what you may want to

```
...
 // Looping if CheckBox number 1 is not selected and the others are not
 // Get an array that tells us for each position whether the item is
 // checked or not
 // --

final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (checkedItems.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No selection info available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```